# Mongodb in a single server then scaling

Tags: mongodb, scaling

If I start with Mongodb on a single server, but foresee that I need to scale out, should I configure it in any specific way? I guess I am looking for tips from people who have gone down this route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Replica Sets and Sharding (the two methods of scaling and redundancy) do not require any special treatment to occur on the solo db so that you may later add them in.  In fact, adding replication is reasonably painless and straight-forward.  (Sharding does require a little more effort, but is still pretty easy.)

Comment: I'd suggest a minor edit to the answer: the only "special treatment" to the solo database server instance would to be to restart it in "replica set mode" and initiate a replica set config on it. Similar handling for sharding. Both are easy, and fairly well documented.

Comment: That is only once the decision to make it a replica set.  Until then, nothing needs to be done.